# WP8.1 HttpClient doesn't download string after first request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, httpclient

I'm wondering for a few days what's going on. I'm writing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 that uses HttpClient to download json string from Internet. It works fine BUT only once after running the app (in OnNavigatedTo event). Later, smashing 'Refresh' button that is supposed to download string again doesn't work. It's still the same string value that has been download as first. On server, this string changes and I can confirm that by looking at it in browser on PC.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace WP8App
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private readonly Uri Website = new Uri("https://some-website.com/files/status.json");
        private HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private async void Button_Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private async void Refresh()
        {
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(Website);
            JsonObject api = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(response);
            TextBox_A.Text = api.value;
            TextBox_B.Text = api.length;
            TextBox_C.Text = api.size;
            TextBox_F.Text = api.volume;
        }

        private async void ShowDialog(string value)
        {
            MessageDialog box = new MessageDialog(value);
            await box.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a master at async, so I count on your eagle eyes xD Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in the `Refresh` method to see if it's really called and returns a different value?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134380/no-cache-with-httpclient-in-windows-phone-8/28266608#28266608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests caching is very aggressive on Windows Phone. The easiest way to bypass it is adding a random parameter at the end of the URL. Something like:

```
private readonly string Website = "https://some-website.com/files/status.json?nocache={0}";
```

Then change the value every time you use it. Using the current timestamp is a good and cheap way to ensure that the URL will always be different:

```
var response = await http.GetStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(Website, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks));
```